# Powershell extract error from a text file on different computers

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract a list of computer having an error in a specific text file. I did the following :

```
$computernames = Get-Content C:\PC.txt 
foreach ($server in $computernames) 
{ 
    $filepath = Test-Path "\\$server\c$\" 


    if ($filepath -eq "True") { 

        Get-Content "\\$server\c$\file.log" | Select-String "Error" -quiet | Select-Object $server 
    } 
}
```

That is returning me the first computer with an error, then only some blank lines in the command window.

If I try to get it in a file with out-file or extract or whatever, I have a blank file.

Thanks in advance for any clue on the matter.

Regards.

Comment: What's the *expected* outcome? Are you interested in the error message or just computer names?

Comment: At the moment only the computers' names. To explain the whole thing.
This log file is related to a service, this can generate only 2 errors, which can be fix or by restarting the service for the 1st case, or by deleting the duplicates in the database for the 2nd case.
The idea at the moment is to get the computers with an error, then try to improve it to automate the resolution, so if error 500 --> restart service, if ducplicate extract GUID and delete from database.
But I'm taking things little by little :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you can do with this. Let me tell you first what you are looking for:

So lets say you have an error , in order to capture that you should use try/catch.

*Replace* :

```
Get-Content "\\$server\c$\file.log" | Select-String "Error" -quiet | Select-Object $server
```

*With This*:

```
        try
        {
         Get-Content "\\$server\c$\file.log" | Select-String "Error" -quiet | Select-Object $server 
        }
        catch
        {
        $Error >> ErrorFile.txt
        }
```

Second thing, I would suggest is. Lets say you have 10 computers and the lets assume the 8th one is having some error. But still you do not wish to stop the loop and proceed with the remaining computers of the loop. In that case you should use 2 try/catch like this:

```
$computernames = Get-Content C:\PC.txt 
try
{
    foreach ($server in $computernames) 
    { 
        $filepath = Test-Path "\\$server\c$\" 
        try{

            if ($filepath -eq "True") { 
                try
                {
                 Get-Content "\\$server\c$\file.log" | Select-String "Error" -quiet | Select-Object $server 
                }
                catch
                {
                $Error >> ErrorFile.txt
                }
            } 
        }
        catch
        {
        $_.Exception.Message >> Errorfile.txt
        }
    }
}
catch
{
$_.Exception.Message >> Errorfile.txt
}
```

So the approach is, if there is any error inside the foreach then the internal catch block will catch it and the error message will be parsed to the errorfile.txt keeping the loop running and will proceed with the remaining computers.

If there is some issue with the main $computernames while getting the content of the file, then it will come to the main catch block with the respective error message parsed and appended in the errorfile.txt

Hope it helps you in understanding the effectiveness of try/catch

Comment: That's not how I understood the question. There are log files that contain some error message and the question is how to search through the files.

Comment: I am testing now, it regards more or less 200 computers so yes I have enough :), the idea is to search the log files with errors, and get the name of the computers with the errors.

Comment: I thought he wants to capture the error in the loop

Comment: well get the error is still a plus, but sadly doesn't work :)